# Strategies to put offline a Spring MVC application running on Cloudfoundry for the purpose of maintenance

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, cloud-foundry

I would be grateful if someone could provide guidance and advice as to how to use cloudfoundry in order to place a Spring MVC app offline so that maintenance can be performed.

The idea is that during the maintenance, all of the website's URLs would redirect to a maintenance page.

Is there any build-in support for this in the Pivotal/Cloudfoundry console?

Any advice, strategies or pointer to documentation welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the maintenance page is an app running on CF, then you can use `cf map-route` and `cf unmap-route` to do this. Given that your app has the name `my-app`, the maintenance page app has the name `maint-app`, and the route to the app is `coolapp.example.com`, that might look like this:

```
$ cf map-route maint-app example.com -n coolapp
$ cf unmap-route my-app example.com -n coolapp
```

After these commands, all requests to `coolapp.example.com` would go to the maintenance page app. After maintenance is complete, you would do the reverse operations.

This is similar to the blue-green zero downtime deployment technique that is described here: http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/blue-green.html.